# Internet Explorer in the ad wheel?

Tags: discussion, advertising, internet-explorer

Why is *the browser that ought not to exist* being advertised on Stack Overflow? After all, this is a programming site, and it gives programmers the most headaches of any browser. And now we advertise it? I vote to remove it.

[image: Advertisement for the browser that shouldn't exist]

Comment: meh, it's not that bad c'mon

Comment: IE, the curse of my life, any post battering you will get +1 from me. (didn't try 9, though)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IE9 is definitely a major improvement over IE8.

Look at it this way: we barely support ancient IE6 at all, and I'd like to push away support of IE7 in some reasonable timeframe since it's problematic as well. The faster we can get IE folks to upgrade to IE9, the better off everyone is.

Comment: Upgrading to IE9 is going to be a major cost item for me. I'm still on XP Pro ;)

Comment: Doesn't 9 run on XP?

Comment: @ArlenBeiler No, IE9 won't do XP.  Vista or better.

Comment: *Anything* that gets people off of IE6/7 is a good thing. I couldn't care less what browser they upgrade to.

Comment: @Chris Vista or better you say? Isn't XP better than Vista?

Comment: @RadekS Good point.  *Vista or **later***.  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Those who have money have power. Sadly enough, Microsoft has money and Stack Exchange needs money. Advertising leads to money and Microsoft pays Stack Exchange for this.

---

By the way, the ad is awful.

> Noob: **Wow! 2D transformations with CSS! Can't wait for 3D!**
>   Pro: **WebKit has already got 3D transformations with CSS.**
>   Noob: **fml**

---

The worst thing is that **this ad shows up on my Mac**. Ads are bad unless they are useful. This ad is not useful for non-IE users. It's even worse if you already are running IE9!

Comment: Well, if it is about keeping Stack Overflow running, then I don't mind. `:)` But why IE, it is free anyway, isn't it?

Comment: @Arlen: advertising is for communication not necessarily for money.